# One to Many relation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, excel, relates

I'm working on ArcMap, and I have a one to many relation between a building column and the residents in the building.

The attribute table for the building has these columns: id,label,number.

I have an excel sheet containing these columns: number,resident

I'm trying to relate the number from building attribute table and the number in the excel sheet.

How to do that?

Comment: It might be important to mention what version of ArcMap you are using.

Comment: I'm using arcMap 10.1

Comment: Try the [ESRI documentation on joining and relating tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @brichins in a comment there is ArcGIS documentation entitled "[About joining and relating tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/)" which provides an excellent introduction and tips like:

> When using data where a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship
>   exists, you should use a relate or relationship class to establish the
>   relationship between the datasets.